# JavaScript: How to remove space in column name and make case insensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ran into a problem this morning whilst working on the web app I am trying to complete.

The app reads an excel file and imports its values to a SQL table.

I perform basic validation and today I realized that sometimes the column headers can have small differences in these excel files. There is no standardization and I have no power to change this issue.

For example, one of the checks:

```
xdata['Meeting ID'] === undefined
```

These are the permutations the column header can have:

Meeting ID
MeetingID
MeetingiD
MeetingId

My question, is there a method to remove the space in between the column header name and make it case insensitive?

I have search the internet for potential solutions but all the solutions I find, affect the column value, not the column header. Perhaps I am using incorrect search words.

If someone has an example on how to handle this, I would be happy to see your idea.

Thank you very much,
Erasmo

UPDATE

After implementing one of the proposed solutions, I am getting an error:

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "normalization". Given some input, coerce it into a "normal" output.

The above is a very simple case:

```
normalizedColumnName = originalColumnName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")
```

EDIT: updated with an example.

```
xData = {
  "Meeting ID": [1,2,3],
  "Something Else": [3,4,5],
}
normalizedXData = {}
Object.keys(xData).map(function(columnName) {
  normalizedXData[ columnName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "") ] = xData[columnName]
})

// normalizedXData === { meetingid: [ 1, 2, 3 ], somethingelse: [ 3, 4, 5 ] }
```

Then from your screenshot, I'd change the undefined check to use "in" instead of undefined:

```
if (!("meetingid" in normalizedXData)) {
    console.log("your error message")
}
```

Comparing to undefined can be tricky, especially with older browsers.

Comment: But that normalizes the value, not the column header name. I need to normalize the header name

Comment: No, that's for the column name. For each column name: update it using the above. Then in your code, you'll only need to look for 'meetingid' no matter how the original excel provided it.

Comment: I included 2 screen shots of the error I am getting returned, I think I am implementing your idea incorrectly.

Comment: Indeed, that's not exactly what I meant, but not far! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Awesome solution. Thank you very much. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 2):

you can use typeof to check if object is string or not, try this

```
normalizedColumnName = typeof data['Meeting'] === 'string' ? data['Meeting'].toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check if string starts with Meeting

```
var n = str.startsWith("Meeting");

if(n === true)
name = "Meeting ID"
```

then use it as `name` variable.

`xdata[name]`

Comment: does this normalizes the value of the column, or the column header name? I need to normalize the header name.